# SQL Server 2012: Select xml with repeated and ungrouped set of elements

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

For the XML below:

```
<Document>
    <ID>01</ID>
    <RaitingDate>2006-05-04T18:13:51.0Z</RaitingDate>
    <MinimumRatingPartner>MinimumRatingPartner1</MinimumRatingPartner>
    <RaitingDate>2006-05-04T18:13:52.0Z</RaitingDate>
    <MinimumRatingPartner>MinimumRatingPartner2</MinimumRatingPartner>
    <RaitingDate>2006-05-04T18:13:53.0Z</RaitingDate>
    <MinimumRatingPartner>MinimumRatingPartner3</MinimumRatingPartner>
</Document>
```

**I would like to generate the following table:**

```
RatingDate                  MRP
-----------------------    ---------------------
2006-05-04 18:13:51.000    MinimumRatingPartner1
2006-05-04 18:13:52.000    MinimumRatingPartner2
2006-05-04 18:13:53.000    MinimumRatingPartner3
```

Now I am getting:

```
RatingDate                  MRP
-----------------------    ---------------------
2006-05-04 18:13:51.000    MinimumRatingPartner1
2006-05-04 18:13:52.000    MinimumRatingPartner1
2006-05-04 18:13:53.000    MinimumRatingPartner1
2006-05-04 18:13:51.000    MinimumRatingPartner2
2006-05-04 18:13:52.000    MinimumRatingPartner2
2006-05-04 18:13:53.000    MinimumRatingPartner2
2006-05-04 18:13:51.000    MinimumRatingPartner3
2006-05-04 18:13:52.000    MinimumRatingPartner3
2006-05-04 18:13:53.000    MinimumRatingPartner3
```

Using this query:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = 
'<Document>
    <ID>01</ID>
    <RaitingDate>2006-05-04T18:13:51.0Z</RaitingDate>
    <MinimumRatingPartner>MinimumRatingPartner1</MinimumRatingPartner>
    <RaitingDate>2006-05-04T18:13:52.0Z</RaitingDate>
    <MinimumRatingPartner>MinimumRatingPartner2</MinimumRatingPartner>
    <RaitingDate>2006-05-04T18:13:53.0Z</RaitingDate>
    <MinimumRatingPartner>MinimumRatingPartner3</MinimumRatingPartner>
</Document>'

SELECT
    RatingDate = s.value('text()[1]', 'datetime')
    ,MRP =r.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')
FROM
    @XML.nodes('Document') as D(V)
cross apply
    D.V.nodes('./RaitingDate') as Q(S)
cross apply
    D.V.nodes('./MinimumRatingPartner') as M(R)
order by MRP, RatingDate
```

I have tried couple other queries, but without success.

**Please note:** XML structure cannot be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML appears to depend on ordered pairs (first partner goes with first date, second partner goes with second date etc etc).  Not only that, but both columns are listed within the same parent node.  So you'll have to do something like this.  Lucky for you xml is order sensitive.

```
DECLARE @XML XML = 
'<Document>
    <ID>01</ID>
    <RaitingDate>2006-05-04T18:13:51.0Z</RaitingDate>
    <MinimumRatingPartner>MinimumRatingPartner1</MinimumRatingPartner>
    <RaitingDate>2006-05-04T18:13:52.0Z</RaitingDate>
    <MinimumRatingPartner>MinimumRatingPartner2</MinimumRatingPartner>
    <RaitingDate>2006-05-04T18:13:53.0Z</RaitingDate>
    <MinimumRatingPartner>MinimumRatingPartner3</MinimumRatingPartner>
</Document>'

SELECT MinimumRatingPartner, RatingDate FROM
(SELECT
    D.V.value('text()[1]', 'datetime') AS RatingDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by @@rowcount) AS RowNum
FROM @XML.nodes('Document/RaitingDate') as D(V)) Dates
INNER JOIN
(SELECT
    D.V.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS MinimumRatingPartner,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by @@rowcount) AS RowNum
FROM @XML.nodes('Document/MinimumRatingPartner') as D(V)) Partners
ON Dates.RowNum = Partners.RowNum
```

Comment: I accepted your answer, because it's without one more inner select statement. And, overall, seems more elegant. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best solution, but works for the given xml

```
SELECT RaitingDate,MinimumRatingPartner 
FROM 
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RaitingDate) AS Num
         ,RaitingDate 
   FROM
        (
            SELECT
            Node.Data.value('(.)[1]','DATETIME') as RaitingDate
            FROM @XML.nodes('/Document/RaitingDate') Node(Data) 
        ) AS A
) AS DateTable

JOIN 

(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MinimumRatingPartner) AS Num
         ,MinimumRatingPartner
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
            Node.Data.value('(.)[1]','VARCHAR(50)') as MinimumRatingPartner
            FROM @XML.nodes('/Document/MinimumRatingPartner') Node(Data) 
        ) AS B
) AS PartnerTable
ON DateTable.Num=PartnerTable.Num
```

Comment: By putting in order of column content you're depending on the alphabetical order of each element - not it's positional order in the XML.  Works in this example, but potentially only by chance.  Unless of course I'm wrong and OPs intent IS alphabetical order.